# How do I install dashing

Tags: ruby, windows, frameworks, dashing

I am new to Ruby and am trying to download the Framework Dashing (http://dashing.io/)

Here is what I have done so far:

- Downloaded RubyDownloader and ran it
- Downloaded dashing-1.3.4.gem
- Opened Start Command Prompt with Ruby

I am now currently confused on what to do next. I have tried reading and watching many tutorials and all it suggests is to install more software.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Run `gem source` and make sure https://rubygems.org/ and http://rubygems.org are both present; if only the former, run `gem source -a http://rubygems.org` to add the (insecure) HTTP-only connection to the list. See if that helps.

FYI, you will also need the Ruby devkit for part of Dashing.

Answer (score 0):

Read the section "Getting Started" on that framework's home page. You should **not** ever have to download .gem files for gems you want to install. Instead, run this:

```
gem install dashing
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian I wrote gem install dashing into the Start Command Prompt With Ruby and I received - "ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'dashing' (>=0)".

Comment: Try running `ruby -v` and tell me what that outputs

Comment: ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: Hmm... my only other suggestion would be to run `gem sources -a https://rubygems.org` and then try `gem install dashing` again. I don't know anything about windows unfortunately.

Comment: After adding 'gem sources -a https://rubygems.org' I received
"Error fetching https://rubygems.org: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0"

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo su -
yum -y update
yum -y remove ruby
yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
sudo \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
rvm install 1.9.3 -- --with-openssl-dir=/etc/pki/tls
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
yum install -y nodejs
gem install dashing bundler aws-sdk-resources 
exit
```

Comment: This was for Windows, not a RedHat based O/S.

Comment: Now you have 2 problems! ;)